# App Insights Status Monitor Extension Failing to deploy with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

I just started getting this failure, not sure why; it was working fine yesterday.  I only changed the appsettings and connectionstrings to be part or resources instead of the webapp to move the dependsOn down the chain.  Previously, the site was dependsOn the dependencies for app settings and connection strings.  Here is the ARM template for the website resource.

```
{
        "comments": "Primary web app deployment.",
        "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "kind": "app",
        "location": "[variables('rgLocation')]",
        "tags": {},
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('planName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "enabled": true,
            "hostNameSslStates": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "sslState": "Disabled"
                },
                {
                    "name": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "sslState": "Disabled"
                }
            ],
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('planName'))]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php",
                    "hostingstart.html"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6",
                "phpVersion": "",
                "pythonVersion": "",
                "nodeVersion": "",
                "linuxFxVersion": "",
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2015",
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "scmType": "None",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                "webSocketsEnabled": false,
                "alwaysOn": true,
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "vnetName": ""
            },
            "microService": "WebSites",
            "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
            "clientCertEnabled": false,
            "hostNamesDisabled": false
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "appsettings",
                "type": "config",
                "apiVersion":"2015-08-01",
                "dependsOn":[
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webAppName'))]",
                    "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('insightsName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('insightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]",
                    "UseAzureStorageEmulator": "false"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "connectionstrings",
                "type": "config",
                "apiVersion":"2015-08-01",
                "dependsOn":[
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webAppName'))]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('genStorageName'))]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('jobStorageName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "AzureStorage": {
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('genStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('genStorageName')), '2017-06-01').keys[0].value, ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]",
                        "type": "Custom"
                    },
                    "AzureWebJobsDashboard" : {
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('jobStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('jobStorageName')), '2017-06-01').keys[0].value, ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]",
                        "type": "Custom"
                    },
                    "AzureWebJobsStorage" : {
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('jobStorageName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('jobStorageName')), '2017-06-01').keys[0].value, ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]",
                        "type": "Custom"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion":"2015-08-01",
                "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                "type": "siteextensions",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {}
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the error I'm getting...

```
STATUS Conflict
PROVISIONING STATE Failed
TIMESTAMP7/14/2017, 10:40:23 AM
DURATION 1 minute 46 seconds
TYPE Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions
RESOURCE ID /subscriptions/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/.../siteextensions/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites
STATUSMESSAGE{
    "status": "Canceled",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Canceled'."
    }
}
```

Even with the error, it actually did install the extension correctly.  During another test, it installed the extension, but when I opened it, the App Insights Profiler web job was not installed.  Either way, not sure why there is a conflict.  When I open the log in Kudu, there is pretty much nothing inside.

```
7/14/2017 2:44:38 PM: [Verbose] Starting Application Insights installation and configuration...
7/14/2017 2:44:38 PM: [Verbose] Loading assembly from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WebSiteManager.dll
7/14/2017 2:44:39 PM: [Verbose] No web.config detected. The web app may be empty. Assume classic ASP.NET by default.
```

That's the entirety of the log.

On a previous test...

```
7/13/2017 6:15:44 PM: [Verbose] Starting Application Insights installation and configuration...
7/13/2017 6:15:44 PM: [Verbose] Loading assembly from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WebSiteManager.dll
7/13/2017 6:15:44 PM: [Verbose] No web.config detected. The web app may be empty. Assume classic ASP.NET by default.
```

Same start of the file, but there are more entries.  There is definitely a web config and the app is working so not sure what that's about.

```
7/13/2017 6:15:50 PM: [Verbose] Application is not instrumented with Application Insights.
7/13/2017 6:15:50 PM: [Verbose] Starting to download/install 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Azure.WebSites' nuget package from D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\appinsights...
7/13/2017 6:15:52 PM, [Verbose] Installing 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights', version '2.3.0' ...
7/13/2017 6:15:53 PM, [Verbose] Installed 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights', version '2.3.0'.
```

The app is definitely instrumented and uses version 2.4 which is newer than 2.3 which was installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be no way to make the extension wait on app setting update so I moved the installation of the extension into a different task in the release environment.  Now I have three tasks:

```
1.  ARM deploy common resources
2.  ARM deploy app dependencies and app service
3.  ARM deploy status monitor site extension
4.  Web Deploy code into app service
```

However, in order to do this, you have to still specify the website somehow in step 3.

Here is what I did using the output from step 2 which has the webAppName, I had to specify the site again and then place the extension into the resources for that site.  You must be careful about what you specify here as to not disrupt the previous deployment.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "webAppName": { "type": "string", "value": "<outputfrompreviousstep>" }
    },
    "variables": {
        "planName": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '-ServicePlan')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": {},
            "dependsOn": [
            ],
            "properties": {
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('planName'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion":"2015-08-01",
                    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                    "type": "siteextensions",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webAppName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "webAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('webAppName')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using VSTS release pipeline, you can use the Azure App Service Manage task to install the extension instead of dealing with the ARM template.

Comment: If you use the release pipeline, you lose the benefit of defining your infrastructure as code.

Comment: Is still a benefit, just has to be run in correct order.  I could orchestrate it via powershell and use release management to kick that off as well.

Comment: Our template was already implemented as Brando Zhang suggested and we were encountering the issue frequently. This is a much better solution!

Answer (score 17):

According to your description, I think the reason why the siteextensions installed has been canceled is changed the appsetting the web app will restarted.So it will cancel the siteextensions installed thread.

After the deployment changed the web app appsetting, it will restart the web app. But your deployment still running the thread which installing the siteextensions. So you face the thread canceled error.

I suggest you could set the appsettings during the web app resource's siteConfig feature. When you deploy the template, it will not cause the web app restart while installing the siteextensions.

Some part of the template you could refer to below codes:

```
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('webSiteName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        }
      ]
```

The whole test template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "brandotestarm11"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "East US",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
      },
      "properties": {
        "applicationId": "[variables('webSiteName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "comments": "Primary web app deployment.",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {},
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('webSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "enabled": true,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name": "[concat(variables('webSiteName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled"
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat(variables('webSiteName'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled"
          }
        ],
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('webSiteName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            }
          ],
          "numberOfWorkers": 1,
          "defaultDocuments": [
            "Default.htm",
            "Default.html",
            "Default.asp",
            "index.htm",
            "index.html",
            "iisstart.htm",
            "default.aspx",
            "index.php",
            "hostingstart.html"
          ],
          "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6",
          "phpVersion": "",
          "pythonVersion": "",
          "nodeVersion": "",
          "linuxFxVersion": "",
          "requestTracingEnabled": false,
          "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
          "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2015",
          "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
          "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
          "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
          "scmType": "None",
          "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
          "webSocketsEnabled": false,
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
          "virtualApplications": [
            {
              "virtualPath": "/",
              "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
              "preloadEnabled": false
            }
          ],
          "autoHealEnabled": false,
          "vnetName": ""
        },
        "microService": "WebSites",
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "clientCertEnabled": false,
        "hostNamesDisabled": false,
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {}

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The result:

[image]

---

Update:

I suggest you could firstly install the web site extensions, then change the appsetting.

In the web app config resources, you could set its depend on the web site extensions.

So the template will firstly install the extensions, then change the appsetting to make the web app restart. So you could install the extensions complete.

More details, you could refer to below template:

You could set the dependsOn with "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites".

```
 "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('webSiteName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]",
            "UseAzureStorageEmulator": "false"
          }
        },
```

The total template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "brandotestarmfor"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "numberOfWorkers": 1,
          "defaultDocuments": [
            "Default.htm",
            "Default.html",
            "Default.asp",
            "index.htm",
            "index.html",
            "iisstart.htm",
            "default.aspx",
            "index.php",
            "hostingstart.html"
          ],
          "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6",
          "phpVersion": "",
          "pythonVersion": "",
          "nodeVersion": "",
          "linuxFxVersion": "",
          "requestTracingEnabled": false,
          "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
          "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2015",
          "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
          "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
          "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
          "scmType": "None",
          "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
          "webSocketsEnabled": false,
          "alwaysOn": true,
          "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
          "virtualApplications": [
            {
              "virtualPath": "/",
              "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
              "preloadEnabled": false
            }
          ],
          "autoHealEnabled": false,
          "vnetName": ""
        },
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "clientCertEnabled": false,
        "hostNamesDisabled": false
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('webSiteName'))]",
            "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('webSiteName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]",
            "UseAzureStorageEmulator": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "East US",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
      },
      "properties": {
        "applicationId": "[variables('webSiteName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: I purposely moved the config out of siteConfig for two reasons:
1.  The config required other resources to be deployed which made the site wait when only the config really needed to wait.
2.  The same configuration is shared with a deployment slot so it seemed to make sense to pull it out.

Comment: As my post says, the appseting deployment will cause your application restart when you installing the siteextensions. In my opinion, the arm template deployment is the first steps, you also don't publish the codes to the web app, so it wait for another resources will not influence your web app. Besides, the only way to make the siteextensions installed completely is using siteconfig without appsetting if you don't want to deploy twice. I suggest you could change the design.

Comment: I can read and acknowledged your suggestion... is there a way to make the extension wait on the config?  It does create a huge delay for no reason by putting config into siteConfig.  Redis can take about 15 minutes which the site can already be deployed if it doesn't have to wait.  cosmos db is another example of long time to complete.  If I have to, create 2 steps in the vsts release pipeline.  First to deploy resources and update config outside of siteConfig, and second to install extensions.

Comment: I suggest you could set the dependson in the appsetting with the site extensions, it will firstly install the site extensions, then install the appsetting. It will work well.

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Comment: preferably it would go the other way around.  the site extension should wait until config is updated.  for instance, the site extension depends on an app setting which will not yet be set in this case.

Comment: I was successful with Brando's approach. Details: https://github.com/tomasr/webapp-appinsights/pull/1

Comment: Our ARM template was already implemented in the manner suggested and we encountered the issue frequently. MPavlak's solution works and now we rarely see it. When we do encounter it, it's because resources are in a deleting state while running the release and the solution in this case is just to wait until the delete has completed.